# Square Picture Taker for android

Tags: android, image, square

I would like to take a square picture for use in an app. Is there a way to launch a camera app that will take a square picture? I'm thinking something like Instagram that has a GUI that contains a square where the picture will be taken, and then returns the picture as a square.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways of doing that.
First one is the easiest and really simple. You can use Intent to launch default camera app and get a photo as a response. The example can be found in documentation [here.](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/media/camera.html#intents)

Another option is to create a [custom](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera) camera app.

Or you can use some library like this [one.](https://github.com/boxme/SquareCamera)

Comment: That library example looks very promising! thank you :)